# Apply multiple CSS classes when an object has a CSS class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, notifications

I have an imported library with a section that allows me to customize it:

```
/* Color setup */
/* You are free to change all of this */
.success{
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    color: white;
}
```

This is the color setup for a popup. Now I want this color setup to use bootstrap's color setup. To achieve this, my solution would be:

```
/* Color setup */
/* You are free to change all of this */
.success{
    addClass: "popup alert-error alert"; //bootstrap classes
}
```

Is this possible ? Or should I just copy and paste bootstrp's code here? I would really hate that solution because it would violate the DRY principle.

Comment: You may be able to achieve something like this using a CSS preprocessor like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). Don't think this can be done in vanilla CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To default to Bootstrap's colors for the .success class, simply remove:

```
.success{
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    color: white;
}
```

To add additional classes to the popup *dynamically*, you could use jQuery (since you are running Bootstrap).

```
$('.success').addClass('popup alert-error alert');
```

This will add those classes to all instances of .success. So being slightly more descript would help.

If this does not need to be done dynamically, **it is best to simply edit the HTML**.

```
<div class="success popup alert-error alert">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply assign two classes in your HTML?

```
<article class="success popup alert-error alert">
```

Alternatively, this should work.

```
.success {
        .popup alert-error alert;
          }
```

Comment: because it is being changed dynamicaly by the Javascript of the libraries. So I either change the library itself, or I find another way, which is what I am trying to do :D

Comment: Your alternative does not compile :S Nice try though!

Comment: I think it's the right direction if nothing else. Its called a 'mixin' worth looking into it.